# Обработка символов

Tags: c++

Написал программу для нахождения в строке( массиве символов ) слова наименьшей длины, и замены этого слова на символ '*'. Программа работает, но при вводе теста типа:"hello hi" заменяет первое слово, хотя должна второе. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в алгоритме.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[255];
    int sum = 0;
    int y = 255;
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int len;

    cin.getline(str, 255);

    while (str[i] != '\0') 
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ' && isalpha(str[i]) && str[i] != '.' && str[i] != '!')
        {
            sum++;
            i++;
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (sum < y) 
            {
                y = sum;
                x = i;
                len = x - sum;
            }

            sum = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = len; i < x; i++) 
    {
        str[i] = '*';
    }

    int z = strlen(str);

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) 
    {
        cout << str[i];
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, код плохо читаемый и не имеет смысла.

Comment: Заголовок относится к содержанию вопроса как?

Comment: Не по делу -  `str[i] != ' ' && isalpha(str[i]) && str[i] != '.' && str[i] != '!'` слишком странное условие. Если уж истинно `isalpha(str[i])`, то все остальные условия истинны автоматически... Еще - исходя из `#include <sstream>` вы намеревались воспользоваться `stringstream` - так почему не воспользовались?

Comment: @Harry не совсем понял как работает класс stringstream

Comment: @Эникейщик название лабораторной работы такое, да и сам метод в посимвольном сравнении isalpha(str[i]), далее замена символа на другой. Может быть, я ошибаюсь, и нельзя такой заголовок ставить. Ну, как поулчилось

Comment: Заголовок должен отражать суть вашей проблемы, а не лабораторной работы.